# Python kivy text input

Tags: python, dictionary, kivy

I'm a newbie at python, and now doing a dictionary with `kivy`. Issue is when I type text, it's not working. Below there I just want to check if it's working or not, so I put some popup, and if input text is `'a'` then print `true`. It's just checking it's working or not, hope you guys help me, thank you.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.bubble import Bubble

class CustomPopup(Popup):
    pass

class Diction(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Diction, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Search"))
        self.search=TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.search)
        if self.search=='A':
            print 'True'
        else:
            print 'False'
        self.add_widget(Button(text="click",on_press=self.show_popup))
    def show_popup(self, b):
        p = CustomPopup()
        p.open()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: If you want to make **kivy** print something on the screen you have to use the tools into the _widgets_ library. I think using just _print_ won't work. So the part inside the **if** just doesn't do anything. Try to trigger and event if True or False, and you will test the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons why is not working:

1. The `if` should be in the method that handles the events, i.e. `show_popup`
2. You should compare the `text` in the `Label`, not the `Label` itself. Instead of `self.search=='A'`, you should use `self.search.text=='A'`

Here is the corrected `__init__` and `show_popup` code:

```
class Diction(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Diction, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Search"))
        self.search=TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.search)
        self.add_widget(Button(text="click",on_press=self.show_popup))

    def show_popup(self, b):
        if self.search.text=='A':
            print 'True'
        else:
            print 'False'
        p = CustomPopup()
        p.open()
```

---

**An alternative approach using the Kivy Language**

The Kivy Language could help you to have a cleaner code. Your code could look like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
# DON'T forget to import Label!!!
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<CustomPopup@Popup>:
    title: "My Custom Poput"    

<Diction@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    search: id_search
    Label:
        text: "Search"
    TextInput:
        id: id_search
    Button:
        text: "click"
        on_press: root.show_popup(self)
""")

class CustomPopup(Popup):
    pass

class Diction(GridLayout):    
    def show_popup(self, b):
        if self.search.text=='A':
            print 'True'
        else:
            print 'False'
    # You can send any content to the popup with the content attribute
    CustomPopup(content=Label(text=self.search.text)).open()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Diction()
```

It helps to keep the logic separated from the interface. You can even keep in separate files if you use the [`load_file`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html?highlight=load_file#kivy.lang.BuilderBase.load_file) function instead of the `load_string`.

Comment: thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense to me, btw what if i want show my translation on popup! am i have to write it like this?
  _CustomPopup(text="self.search.text") or in kv language <CustomPopup@Popup>: 
       text:self.search.text ???_

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. (1) I can tell you that `Popup` has no attribute `text`. Do you mean title? or do you mean a `Widget` (probably a `Label`) with the text? (2) The 2nd option is wrong because `search` doesn't belong to `CustomPopup`. I ll try to give you another example, but you better ask a different question for it, so more ppl get to read it and reply.

Comment: I modify the example so you can send `content` to your `CustomPopup`. You probably don't want a `CustomPopup`, it might be more useful to have a "`CustomContent`". The `content` property of `Custom` will accept any Widget.

Comment: Regarding the use of kv language, you can always access any id inside the class scope. For example, you could have done something like `on_press: print id_search.text` because on_press is inside the of the `Diction` scope. However you cannot access `id_search` in `CustomPopup` because `id_search` belongs to `Diction`. Lastly, the `search` attribute is meant to be used used in Python. Nonetheless, it can be access with `root.search` (or `self.parent.search`).

Comment: Thanks, you get it right, CustomContent is very useful also really new to me. Now i finally found myself again. thanks again